# create planner plans and add them as teams tabs using Graph API is raising this error "Invalid bind property name teamsApp in request."

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, power-automate, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I am trying to join the approaches mentioned in these 2 links:-

https://michelcarlo.com/2023/09/01/using-the-http-with-azure-ad-connector-in-power-automate-to-create-planner-plans-and-add-them-as-teams-tabs/

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Flow-creates-team-channel-but-channel-is-hidden/td-p/1677813

where i want to create a standard channel inside existing Microsoft Teams + create a new Planner + show the new Planner inside the new channel tab.. here what i did so far:-

1. Get the Teams + create a standard channel:-

[image]

2. Parse the JSON and create a new Planner plan

[image]

3. Parse the json + get the Planner Id

[image]

4. Finally , show the Planner Plan inside a channel tab.

[image]

here is the body of the http request:-

```
{
    "displayName": "@{triggerOutputs()?['body/Title']}",
    "teamsApp@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.planner",
    "configuration": {
        "entityId": "@{body('Parse_JSON_2')?['id']}",
        "contentUrl": "https://tasks.teams.microsoft.com/teamsui/{tid}/Home/PlannerFrame?page=7&auth_pvr=OrgId&auth_upn={userPrincipalName}&groupId={groupId}&planId=@{variables('PlannerID')}&channelId={channelId}&entityId={entityId}&tid={tid}&userObjectId={userObjectId}&subEntityId={subEntityId}&sessionId={sessionId}&theme={theme}&mkt={locale}&ringId={ringId}&PlannerRouteHint={tid}",
        "removeUrl": "https://tasks.teams.microsoft.com/teamsui/{tid}/Home/PlannerFrame?page=13&auth_pvr=OrgId&auth_upn={userPrincipalName}&groupId={groupId}&planId=@{variables('PlannerID')}&channelId={channelId}&entityId={entityId}&tid={tid}&userObjectId={userObjectId}&subEntityId={subEntityId}&sessionId={sessionId}&theme={theme}&mkt={locale}&ringId={ringId}&PlannerRouteHint={tid}",
        "websiteUrl": "https://tasks.office.com/{tid}/Home/PlanViews/@{variables('PlannerID')}?Type=PlanLink&Channel=TeamsTab"
    }
}
```

but on the last request i am getting this error:-

```
Invalid bind property name teamsApp in request.
```

any advice on this please?

Thanks

Comment: In examples I see that `teamsApp@odata.bind` contains guid not a name `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.planner` => `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/{id}`

Comment: @user2250152 and what should this GUID contain?

Comment: Do you know the id of a team app?

Comment: @user2250152 yes i have it, let me try .. thanks a lot

Comment: @user2250152 also in this example https://michelcarlo.com/2023/09/01/using-the-http-with-azure-ad-connector-in-power-automate-to-create-planner-plans-and-add-them-as-teams-tabs/ the `teamsApp@odata.bind` contain text and not id

Comment: @user2250152 i tried to pass the teams id, but got the same error `Invalid bind property name teamsApp in request.`